# Paragraph will not center using css commands

Tags: html, css

Hey I am confused since I am trying to center a paragraph for instance it wont do anything i tried text-align, align center, inline block and so on.

HTML `

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 picText1">
              <p style="background-color:#77b97a;"  class="picText">Ovenstående billeder er taget fra M.E.G.A spillet, som er en Role-Playing-Game simulation udformet i Unity Virtual-Reality hvor spilleren agerer statsminister, som har ubegrænset kontrol over de danske klimalove samt budgettet som medfølger.</p>
          </div>`
```

CSS

```
.picText{
          color: black;
          border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
          width: 150%;
          height: 75px;
          padding-top: 2%;
          position: relative;
          text-align: center;
          left: 26%;
        }
```

I also tried using bootstrap command with no luck hope someone can clarify since it works sometimes with text align and so on, but i have put borders around it seems like it wont do anything

Comment: What version of bootstrap?

Comment: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need the positioning styles to get the paragraph centered. You can simply specify the width of the element, and then set its margins to `0 auto` which will give it 0 margin for top and bottom, and will automatically use the correct left and right margins to make the element centered given its box model and the width of its parent container.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.picText {
  background-color: #77b97a;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  padding: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="picText">Ovenstående billeder er taget fra M.E.G.A spillet, som er en Role-Playing-Game simulation udformet i Unity Virtual-Reality hvor spilleren agerer statsminister, som har ubegrænset kontrol over de danske klimalove samt budgettet som medfølger.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/84312254ed0994a2ead9cd270e986b44 still not aligned tried doing that and rename the parent div to mycontainer but still not aligned

Comment: it will be centered to the inner width of its parent. So in that layout, it looks like you want the picText element to be a child of the same element as the picture above it, which is centered. honestly i'd have to see the rest of your source to tell you for sure, but the key here is that using `margin: auto;` will center it based on the available space of its parent.

Comment: oh ye i just found out you were right i made a stupid mistake. It is centered now with this command thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap, I used a container and centered it using `justify-content-center` which is simpler than writing css rules in my opinion. You could add your image inside the container and they both will be centered.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container col-md-6 justify-content-center w-50">
  <p class="bg-info rounded-lg p-2 mt-3">
    Ovenstående billeder er taget fra M.E.G.A spillet, som er en Role-Playing-Game simulation udformet i Unity Virtual-Reality hvor spilleren agerer statsminister, som har ubegrænset kontrol over de danske klimalove samt budgettet som medfølger.
  </p>
</div>
```